# From where is archive.php getting its posts?

Tags: wp-query, archives

My archive.php starts like this:

```
        get_header(); ?>
        <?php if( have_posts() ): ?>
            <div id="container" class="portfolio-wrapper">
            <?php while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
```

I'm curious... where is the actual WP Query made? For example when I press on a Category or on an Archive link, I get to this page, but where's the actual select done?

More specifically, I'm curious where the first query is created (in what file), since the above only **uses** a query which was already made somewhere.

I'm asking because I want to create a custom archive (using a shortcode with posts ids in it) and I want to decide what is the best approach to do that :).

Comment: Google "WordPress main query" for the general answer to your general question. For detailed help with your problem please [edit] the question to include as much detail as you can about what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I think my question was pretty clear to begin with. I've edited it further :). The Google search has no useful result. I am not interested in what is the "main query" or The Loop. I know what those are and that information is not useful for making me understand the flow of things under the hood.

Comment: "I know what those are." -- No you don't. The "main query" is "where the first query is created". Understand that, you understand most of your question. As far as "no useful result", the second result is the one you want-- including the location of the file(s) involved.

Comment: The second result is "The Loop". So are you saying that simply asking for "the_post()" in any listing is actually the only thing required? No query needs to be configured? So then how does The Loop know that I'm requesting the posts for the year 2014 for example?

Comment: You are getting slightly different results than I am but I am sure there is one about `WP_Query`, which handles all of your post, page, archive, single, CPT, etc. queries. At any rate, tracing the function calls from any of the related functions will get you to the same place.

Comment: I understand that you're trying to help me in your own way, and I am sorry if I seem to not have "worked" for my answer (although I have). The next time you try to "discipline" somebody in this way, I would advise actually at least specifying the title of the link in your Google Results :). I have also read about WP_Query, but only now I understand that the place to start looking is in the wp-blog-header (which further leads to "class-wp.php"). Thank you for your help :).

Comment: Everyone calm down. :) This is a pretty good question and I concur that existing info on it kind of tends to suck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main query is set up by `WP` class (curiously little known, since there is rarely reason to mess with it). It happens in between WP core finishing load and proceeding to load template, in `wp-blog-header.php`.

Note that some nuances of implementation:

- `WP` class works on a global, set up *earlier* in `wp-settings.php`
- the global it works on is `$wp_the_query`, which acts at *original* instance from which more commonly used `$wp_query` is spawned. This two-variable implementation is used for detection if the main query had been modified, among other things.

Comment: I keep stumbling over this question in my own work, and it's probably worth adding: if you are dealing with the actions or filters used by get_posts, there are a number of different wp_query instances which can get used in the context of archive.php (and many of them have nothing to do with the posts which will be displayed).